# How do I access my Windows files from Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 as an alternate boot to Vista on my PC.  When I boot to Ubuntu, however, the only hard drives I can see from the GUI are the two external USB drives that I have.  I cannot see the main drive (what Vista calls "C") from the Ubuntu user interface, and therefore, I cannot access the bulk of my files and folders on the C drive.

I require full access to all of my file systems, and I need to know whether or not Ubuntu 12.04.3 has an intuitive way to accomplish that. I would prefer to access them via a GUI, but I am ok with a terminal based solution.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on its own partition or with WUBI?

Comment: Open a terminal (look for it on the dash) and type the command `sudo fdisk -l`, what is the output of it? Edit your question with more information please.

Comment: Hey, I edited your post to remove the parts that are not objective to the question, that will decrease the chance of people down voting it and increase the chance that you get some proper help. Please be aware that this is not a "forum" so all the necessary information should be in your post, the more information you give the better.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu via `wubi`, the former `C:\` drive is mounted at `/host`.

If you didn't, check if you have the package `ntfs-3g` (ntfs-driver) installed:

`dpkg --list | grep ntfs-3g`

If the package is installed, the beginning of the output line will read `ii  ntfs-3g`.

Also, `mount` lists all mounted partitions and where they are mounted.

For the terminal, see RPi Awesomeness' answer.